# Create dynamically custom Tooltips containing Image and Title in Asp.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, tooltip

I want to Create dynamically, custom Tooltips like [this](http://jquerytools.org/demos/tooltip/any-html.html) or [this](http://rndnext.blogspot.gr/2009/02/jquery-ajax-tooltip.html) from code Behind, this is what I 've got so far.

```
 public void printSubjects()
{
    SqlConnection con = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection();
    con.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["beta"].ConnectionString;

    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select SUBJECT_ID,X_COOR,Y_COOR from M_SUBJECT WHERE TERRITORY_ID =" + Convert.ToInt32(ddMaps.SelectedItem.Value) + " AND X_COOR !='" + 0 + "'", con);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds, "SubjectLinked");
    points = new Button[ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count];

    for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++ )
    {
        points[i] = new Button();
        points[i].CssClass = "fixPoint";
        points[i].Style.Add("top", ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Y_COOR"].ToString() + "px");
        points[i].Style.Add("left", ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["X_COOR"].ToString() + "px");

        SqlDataAdapter daII = new SqlDataAdapter("select USER_NAME from I_SUBJECT WHERE ID =" + Convert.ToInt32(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["SUBJECT_ID"].ToString()) + "", con);
        DataSet dsII = new DataSet();
        daII.Fill(dsII, "SubjectName");

        points[i].ToolTip = dsII.Tables[0].Rows[0]["USER_NAME"].ToString();


        points[i].Click += new EventHandler(deleteLink_Click);

        myID.Controls.Add(points[i]);
    }

}
```

And this is the result   [image]

How to implement jquery qtip or ajax hover menu or anything else in order to add Subject Image and Other Subject Info inside each Tooltip from Code behind..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I ended up using [ASPNetToolTip](http://www.aspnettooltip.com/aspnettooltip_Demonstration.aspx). In the .cs file I made an HtmlTable with Subject's Title(Label) and Image(img) and then I passed it to the AspNetToolTip and that did the trick. 
I didn't bother with any Javascript or Html code, all the code was written in C#.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a custom control. When you override the Render method, you provide the Html Code you want to be written in the page.

Here is a sample: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa310915(v=vs.71).aspx

And the full literature if you have time and will: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt27tfhy(v=vs.100).aspx

Hope this helps